# IActivityLogger doesnot log PromptDialog.Choice text

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

I am using IActivityLogger to log the conversation between bot and user.
Here the logger is logging all the messages except the text is being generated by PromptDialog.Choice()

I have tested for other methods of PromptDialog like

```
PromptDialog.Confirm()
PromptDialog .Text()
```

These are working i meant text from these methods are being logged, only the PromptDialog.Choice text is not hitting the IActivityLogger.

Logger.cs

```
public class Logger : IActivityLogger
    {
        public async Task LogAsync(IActivity activity)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(activity.AsMessageActivity()?.Text);
        }
    }
```

RootDialog.cs

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            string[] choices = new string[]{ "choice 1" , "choice 2"};
            PromptDialog.Choice(context, resumeAfterPrompt, choices, "please choose an option.");
        }

        private async Task resumeAfterPrompt(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            await context.PostAsync((await result).ToString());
            context.Done<object>(null);
        }
```

Every other to and from messages are going through the Logger class except the PromptDialog.Choice() from the RootDialog.

Comment: Can you add a quick example of this and indicate exactly what content (what line of code) is not hitting the logger?

Comment: @NicolasR I have updated the question. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2635

Comment: Please, please, please do not put code other than variable assignment in `StartAsync`.  I have never seen a single person put logic in `StartAsync` and have it behave as they would have thought it would.

Comment: @JasonSowers I will keep in mind what you said, now will the change you suggested solve my problem or it is just a good practice to follow?

Comment: @Harsh Raj  It's a best practice thing.  I added an answer I hope helps.  I think that you will need to look into to adding case logging for more that just this.  The code may not be perfect, but it should give you the general idea

Comment: You could also just store the entire activity in a field.  var activitySerialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(activity.AsMessageActivity());

Answer (score 3):

> the PromptDialog.Choice text is not hitting the IActivityLogger

I create a sample and try to reproduce the issue, I find that it can hit the logger when I selected a option from `PromptDialog.Choice` options list.

*RootDialog:*

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {

        string[] choices = new string[] { "choice 1", "choice 2" };
        PromptDialog.Choice(context, resumeAfterPrompt, choices, "please choose an option.");
    }

    private async Task resumeAfterPrompt(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        string choice = await result;

        await context.PostAsync($"You sent {choice}");
        //context.Done<object>(null);
    }
}
```

*Logger:*

```
public class DebugActivityLogger : IActivityLogger
{
    public async Task LogAsync(IActivity activity)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(activity.AsMessageActivity()?.Text);
    }
}
```

*Emulator test result:*

[image]

*VS Output window:*

[image]

Besides, if you set breakpoint inside your Logger to debug and trace the activity, you would find the `activity.AsMessageActivity()?.Text` will be `""` when it renders a HeroCard to prompt user for one of a set of choices.

[image]

So a empty string will be written to VS Output window.

[image]

Comment: Ya Fei u are correct, i have given one link  github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2635 in the comment there i have seen this issue that PromptDialog.Choice goes as HeroCard so it is not being logged there in IActivityLogger. But can you please tell me any solution for that. Any alternate solution. For now i am manually logging the Prompt text and Prompt options but that does not seem good to do like logging every places manually.

Answer (score 1):

I very briefly tested this, but it should work. If inside your `IActivityLogger` implementation you drill down farther than just `activity.text`. Some Activities may need and you can do it by simply using some if statements.  I think there are more cases you will need to drill down into an activity for more than just the activity.text property than just this case. So using a similar strategy to log the information you would like to log for other unique types of content should work for you.

Something like this for example:

```
public class Logger : IActivityLogger
{
    public async Task LogAsync(IActivity activity)
    {
        IMessageActivity a = activity.AsMessageActivity();

        //loop through for cases there are multiple attachments
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Attachments.Count; i++)
        {
            //in the case of herocard
            if (a.Attachments[i].ContentType == "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero")
            {
                //log something, i randomly picked a property
                Debug.WriteLine(a.Attachments[i].Name);
            }
            //another case
            if (a.Attachments[i].ContentType.Contains("image"))
            {
                //Maybe save the image somewhere
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(activity.AsMessageActivity()?.Text);
    }
}
```